# How to keep session data on order success page so that you can work on it in magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-success-page

In mage1 there was `$session->clear()` but cannot find where it is done in magento2?

I thought it was `$this->checkoutSession->clearQuote()->clearStorage();` in

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Observer/UnsetAllObserver.php
```

but it's not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Check following file and code.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php)

```
# Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php

$session->clearQuote();
```

Comment: tried that one too, but now it is working, obvious solution thanks.

Comment: Link Check following file and code. is not working

Answer (score 1):

Another quicker way to do this is to edit the `isValid()` method in

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session/SuccessValidator.php

and set an existing order id, then navigate to your success page (site.com/checkout/onepage/success)

See [https://github.com/magepal/magento2-preview-checkout-success-page](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-preview-checkout-success-page/blob/master/Plugin/Model/Session/SuccessValidatorPlugin.php)

```
$orderId = 123;
$incrementId = '000001'

$this->checkoutSession
     ->setLastOrderId($orderId)
     ->setLastRealOrderId($incrementId);

     return true;
```

Comment: it works perfect in 2.2